# Dual-monitors with one VGA port?

Tags: display, vga, multiple-monitors

Would it be possible to use some sort of splitter to make Windows display to the other monitor as if I had two ports (both unique, not cloning from the primary.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically yes, but it would be non-trivial as the device would need to be able to read the DDC information of both monitors and return fake DDC information to the computer for a display large enough to span across both, and then it would need to reprocess the VGA signals coming from the computer and insert appropriate timing sequences for each monitor. I know of no device that does this.

Comment: I agree, it is possible that there could be a device that splits one VGA signal into one double wide output and then splits it into two monitors. However, I do not know of any device that would do this.

Comment: It really just is not practical to do that. You'd spend less just buying a second video card, or one with two ports. nVidia GT 210's are like $30 now

Comment: @Simon: Sure, if your system can support additional cards, or even cards at all in the first place. It would still be (moderately) useful for embedded devices, which lack such capability.

Comment: My system can support video cards, but I'm stuck with an AGP port for now (and I don't have the money for a brand-new card.).

Comment: @Alexander: As noted in my answer, there is a device that does exactly what you're looking for, but you'll probably spend just as much on it as you would on a medium-end graphics card.

Comment: There are devices that do more or less this, such as the Matrox products linked in other answers.

Comment: I researched this myself for work recently. The DualHead systems are a couple to several hundred dollars, which prices them out of the casual "I just want two unique monitors from one" field. With a simple splitter, the only option is cloning from a single VGA. Even most DVI only support one monitor as well.

Answer (score 10):

The [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/) can do that for you. I believe it simply creates a virtual monitor that is twice as wide as the attached monitors, and then splits the resulting signal and sends it to the respective physical monitor.

As Xantec pointed out in the comments, they also have a [3-monitor version](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) which can handle up to 3 monitors.

Comment: ah, you beat me. Also available is the [TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) should you want to use three monitors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a device that will add a second VGA connection using a USB port.  Is that a possible solution?  If so, I can find you a link.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a USB port, you can pick up a USB to DVI or VGA connector cheaper than most video cards.

1. [Plugable USB to DVI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038P1TP4) ~$65 - I use this one and it's dead simple to install.
2. [Plugable USB to VGA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004D0QC0A) ~$45

Comment: Does that clone from the main display, or is each display show a unique view?

Comment: Alexander, it does whatever you want it to do. You can clone an existing display, extend the desktop, turn that display to portrait. It's as if you had another DVI or VGA port available.